# PHP images not showing

Tags: php, html

I have the following code

```
<img src="image/<?php echo $row['productImage'];?>" class="img-responsive" style=" width: 100px;" /><br />  
                           <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $row['`productName`'];?></h4>
                           <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $row['productCategory'];?></h4>                            
                           <h4 class="text-danger">$<?php echo $row['productPrice'];?></h4>
```

Everthing works fine except the first line that is supposed to display an image. `productImage` `productName` `productCategory` and `productPrice` are all columns in a mysql database table called `products`. `productImage` is a `VARCHAR(100)` which stores the string `img/shockAbsober.jpg` which is the relative path to the image I wish to display. The image itself is in a folder called img which is in my project folder. I don't see why the image won't display. Any help will be greatly appriciated. Also I am new to PHP

Comment: So the image is located at image/img/shockAbsober.jpg?

Comment: I think zach nailed it on the head. You probably just need to change <img src="image/... to <img src="img/...

Comment: Thank you Zach and Jdub! Problem solved. When I followed a tutorial last week I assumed it was part of the syntax and not a reference to a folder.